# Find out what controller and method executed helper function (from within the helper function itself)

Tags: php, laravel, backend

Let's say we have a helper function, logDatabaseError($exception) that logs QueryExceptions to a special log.

helpers.php

```
function logDatabaseError ($exception) {
    $controller = ????;
    $function = ????;

    $log_string = "TIME: ".now().PHP_EOL;
    $log_string.= "User ID: ".Auth::user()->id.PHP_EOL;
    $log_string.= "Controller->Action:".$controller."->".$function.PHP_EOL;
    $log_string.= $exception.PHP_EOL;

    Storage::disk('logs')->append('database.log', $log_string);
}
```

This function is called from multiple controllers and multiple functions within those controllers.

Whenever something needs to be written to the database, in the catch part, we call this logDatabaseError function and pass to it the \Illuminate\Database\QueryException as $exception.

BestControllerEverController.php

```
class BestControllerEver extends Controller
{
    function writeStuffToDatabase (Request $request) {
        try {
            DB::does-its-thing
        } 
        catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $exception) {
            logDatabaseError($exception)
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible for the logDatabaseError function to get both Controller name and function name without passing them as function parameters?

In this particular example case, $controller and $function variables in logDatabaseError function would be set to BestControllerEver and writeStuffToDatabase, respectively.

I know this is logged in the stack trace, but their location in $exception object is not always the same and extracting it from there is not reliable, at least from my limited experience.

Comment: Not really, but Exceptions do have [`getFile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getfile.php) and [`getLine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getline.php) that help to find where it was being thrown from

Comment: If the call is made directly from a controller/action then you can use `Route::currentRouteAction();`, `\Route::current()`, and `\Route::currentRouteName()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, getFile() seems to always return Connection.php as the source file; which is technically correct, but not what I want @aynber

Comment: Thank you, using Routes for this did not cross my mind and it is good enough as a solution! @waterloomatt

P.S.: Route::current() seems to not play nice with stringification, but it does matter in this case as other two functions get the job done.

Comment: you can get those information from the request helper or route interface and send them to your logDatabaseError as parameters.

Comment: It seems using the Route interface in the helper function logDatabaseError itself works just fine, so no need to pass it as parameters :) Thank you for commenting! @N69S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function to trace the error frames. Since [spatie/backtrace](https://github.com/spatie/backtrace) is using debug_backtrace behind the scenes You can use the [package](https://github.com/spatie/backtrace)

Install the package into application by running

```
composer require spatie/backtrace
```

Put that in your controller:

```
try {
            \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('myunavialbetable')->get();
        } 
        catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $exception) {
            logDatabaseError($exception);
        }
```

Inside your helper file

```
function logDatabaseError ($exception) {

    $backtrace = Spatie\Backtrace\Backtrace::create();

    $controllerResponsible = collect($backtrace->frames())   
    ->filter(function(Spatie\Backtrace\Frame $frame){
        return ($frame->class);
    })
    ->filter(function(Spatie\Backtrace\Frame $frame){
        return is_subclass_of($frame->class, App\Http\Controllers\Controller::class);
    })
    ->first();   

    $log_string = "TIME: " . now() . PHP_EOL;
    $log_string .= "User ID: " . auth()->id() . PHP_EOL;
    if ($controllerResponsible){
        $log_string .= "Controller->Action:" . $controllerResponsible->class . "->" . $controllerResponsible->method . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $log_string .= $exception . PHP_EOL;

    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('logs')->append('database.log', $log_string);

// if you want to use on-demand log feature you can uncomment this
```

//This feature is available from Laravel v8.66.0

```
    // Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::build([
    //     'driver' => 'single',
    //     'path' => storage_path('logs/database.log'),
    // ])->info($log_string);
}
```

> NOTE:CONTROLLER MUST EXTEND `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`

> **ADVANCE SOLUTION**

Steps to be followed:

1. Install [spatie/backtrace](https://github.com/spatie/backtrace)
2. Remove try/catch block from controller.
3. Modify `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` to below content

````
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public $controllerResponsible = null;

    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {

            $backtraceInstance = SpatieBacktrace::createForThrowable($e);

            $controllerResponsible = collect($backtraceInstance->frames())
                ->filter(function (SpatieBacktraceFrame $frame) {
                    return ($frame->class);
                })
                ->filter(function (SpatieBacktraceFrame $frame) {
                    return is_subclass_of($frame->class, \App\Http\Controllers\Controller::class);
                })
                ->first();

            $this->controllerResponsible = $controllerResponsible;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the default context variables for logging.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function context()
    {
        $extraContext = [];

        if ($this->controllerResponsible instanceof SpatieBacktraceFrame) {
            $extraContext['controller'] = $this->controllerResponsible->class;
            $extraContext['method'] = $this->controllerResponsible->method;
            $extraContext['controller@method'] = $this->controllerResponsible->class . '@' . $this->controllerResponsible->method;
        }

        return array_merge(parent::context(), $extraContext);
    }
}```

So here is what happens.

By default you can add exta [content][3] by overriding context method inside `Handler.php`. And you dont need any other custom log. It will be logged by default logging.
````

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Comment: Right now I am working on more advanced solution I will post is shortly

Answer (score 0):

As per [@waterloomatt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296555/waterloomatt)'s comment, the Route facade seems to provide a close enough solution:

using

```
$route_action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

we can get output

> App\Http\Controllers\BestControllerEver@writeStuffToDatabase

written into the log.

While this really only returns functions that are registered as routes, knowing where users encounter an error is enough; combined with the fact a full stack trace is also included in the $exception that gets passed to logDatabaseError.

P.S.:
If you use this solution, remember to set

```
$route_action = (Route::currentRouteAction()) ? Route::currentRouteAction() : "Not registered as route!"
```

just in case.